# How do I correctly obscure multiple overlapping plots by fill?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure where I wish to fill under each plot to obscure the plots behind it.

My desired result is akin to this example:

[image: Figure where each plot obscures every other plot where the other plot is less than the plot.]

I think I need to set the `zorder` of either `plot` or `fill_between` (or both?), but I can't seem to get the correct combinations.

My current plot and code are below.

[image]

My current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-(x - mu)*(x - mu) / (2 * sig*sig))


mus = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4]
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)

for i in range(len(mus) - 1, -1, -1):
    mu = mus[i]
    y = gaussian(x, mu, 1) + i * 0.1
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.fill_between(x, y, 0, color="lightgray")  # The plot lines are not hidden by the fill. Probably need to do something with zorder

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

and of course, I find the answer after I ask...

```py
for i in range(len(mus) - 1, -1, -1):
    mu = mus[i]
    y = gaussian(x, mu, 1) + i * 0.1
    zorder = len(mus) - i #zorder increases as I draw the plots "in front"
    plt.plot(x, y, zorder=zorder)
    plt.fill_between(x, y, 0, color="lightgray", zorder=zorder)
```